# How to retrieve SQALE rating and Technical debt information?

Tags: .net, rest, sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I was looking at the web service API V5.5 documentation for SonarQube and would like to retrieve two things at the project level:

1. SQALE rating
2. Technical Debt

Which API can I exactly use to get these values directly?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify the version of SonarQube. Post-5.6 this is no more "SQALE Rating" as such.

Comment: Edited, the version i am working on is 5.5

Comment: 5.6 is the current LTS. You're going to have a hard time finding help for versions prior to that. In general, this should be retrievable tho from the measures (metrics?) web services

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, I did that but what i get in the json response doesn't seem to be matching with the value on screen

Comment: Perhaps [edit] your question to show a) your web service calls, and b) what you get versus what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the The SQALE Rating using Web Service API Sonarqube

```
GET URLSONARQUBE/api/resources?metrics=sqale_rating
```

Comment: What sonar version is that one. I don't have that endpoint in Version 6.7.3